# Display items of an array in one page NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to display an array of search results after the termination of a loop.

How do I display the results of an array in one page?

```
app.post('/search', function (req, res) {
  while (searchvalues.length > 0) {
    searchvalues.pop();
  }
  var searchitem = req.body.Search;

  for (var i = 0; i < booksNames.length; i++) {

    if (booksNames[i].includes(searchitem)) {

      // res.render('searchresults',{err:"  "+booksNames[i]});
      searchvalues.push(booksNames[i]);
      console.log(booksNames[i]);
    }
  }

  if (searchvalues.length == 0) {
    //res.render('searchresults',{err:"  "+booksNames[i]});
    res.render('searchresults', { err: '  This book is not found' })
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < searchvalues.length; i++) {

      res.render('searchresults', { err: "" + searchvalues[i] });

    }
  }

});
```

This is my POST request for searching; keeping in mind that I want to differentiate between each request because I will need to add links to every item in the array later.

Answer (score 0):

You should call res.render function outside the for loop and send whole searchValues array rather than the i. index.

Comment: this solution won't work for me because I want to have different href value for every item in the array to be accessed later

Comment: I need them to be separated objects in order to assign different links to them later

Comment: You can add href values to the searchValues and create a html string based on searchValues. Then you can res.send(html)